# Security minecraft server mods containing Java code

Tags: security, minecraft

I am running a Java minecraft server on my Linux server. I have been asked to install some mods (e.g. data packs) on the server which appear to contain Java code written by a third party other than Mojang.

Is this Java code restricted in what it can do, or can it run any arbitrary code it likes (e.g. read /etc/passwd, open TCP ports, claim huge amounts of memory, etc.)?

In other words, how risky are minecraft mods containing Java code?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question. I actually was wondering that too. I have spent a bit of time looking at the binaries of minecraft and the minecraft server spigot. I assume we both use the Java Edition.

First of all, the Java code, once you run it on a host, can do anything. The only mechanism that can prevent that and protect the user from the developer in Java, is the security manager. Once you turn on the security manager (which is an opt-in mechanism) you have the ability to define a set of rules that Java will obey like e.g. it will not write into directories you don't allow it too.

So the question is: is minecraft using the security manager per default. I am 99% sure it does not. No one is using the security manager because it is a pain to configure it right and things stop working every time you get it wrong (you know that an applications uses the security manager because you face problems with policy misconfiguration every now and then).

Running minecraft is made by running an exe. I would not now where to turn the security manager on even if I would like too. There is a bit of hope with the spigot server. You can install the security manager with `-Djava.security.manager` and input your policy with `-Djava.security.policy==my.policy`. But getting the policy right will be pain. I will try to look into it though when I have a free week or so.

Comment: "is minecraft using the security manager per default. I am 99% sure it does not." If the mods are Forge mods, then Forge does use the security manager, but it only uses it to stop `System.exit` from ruining crash reports, not to actually enforce any sort of security.

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft mods can act with the full permissions of the user running Minecraft. If you don't trust the author of a mod, then there's basically two approaches to safely use it:

1. Audit the source code yourself, and then compile the mod yourself so you know it matches the binary
2. Run Minecraft in a sandbox such as a VM, or as a heavily restricted user.